# Is it true that $(4+\sqrt{14})(4-\sqrt{14}) = (4+\sqrt{14})^2$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{14})$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Is it true that $(4+\sqrt{14})(4-\sqrt{14}) = (4+\sqrt{14})^2$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{14})$? I am going through the solution of a problem I'm working on and this seems to be what they are saying. If its true, why so? I see that the left hand side is $(2)$ and the right hand side is $(2(15+4\sqrt{14}))$ but then what?

Comment: No it is not true.

Comment: It is simply not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true, if you are talking about ideals.

Clearly, $(2(15+4\sqrt{14})) \subset (2)$. For the other inclusion, note that $(15+4\sqrt{14})(15-4\sqrt{14}) = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

No. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{14})$ is an integral domain, so if we had equality it would imply that

$$4 - \sqrt{14} = 4 + \sqrt{14}$$

by cancelling a factor of $4 + \sqrt{14}$ from each side. Rearranging would lead to $2 \sqrt{14} = 0$, which is false.